# Updating record via REST does not trigger workflow, CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a workflow that wait three days and check a boolean field. If the boolean is yes do something, else finish as completed. That boolean field is default no and change to yes with an update via javascript.

I don't know why the workflow always do something even when the boolean field is no.

Javascript updates are not recognized by Dynamics CRM?

Code I'm using to update:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.BooleanField= true;

var jsonEntity = window.JSON.stringify(obj);

var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/CustomEntity";
var ODataPath = serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: ODataPath + "(guid'" + CustomEntityId + "')",
    data: jsonEntity,
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
    },
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus + "; ErrorThrown: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is your workflow triggered off?

Comment: My workflow wait 3 days and check the boolean field. I refer as "triggered" to the fact that even the value changed, workflow don't recognize the change. @t-mckeown

Comment: Does the modifiedon field for the record gets updated after the rest operation?